# PdfReadWarning: PdfFileReader stream/file object is not in binary mode

Tags: python-2.7, pypdf

I have many pdf pages that I want to merge them into one file.

My script is as follow:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger,PdfFileReader
filename_list=[]
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for i in range (0,66):
    filename='page'+str(i)+'.pdf'
    if not filename in filename_list:
        filename_list.append(filename)
for filename in filename_list:
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filename),'rb'))
merger.write('output.pdf')
```

When I ran it, it gave me the warning "PdfReadWarning: PdfFileReader stream/file object is not in binary mode. It may not be read correctly. [pdf.py:792]"

I'm not sure why it is doing that. Can anyone have any suggestions? (I used pypdf2)

Very much appreciated!

Comment: I found my mistake. It should be merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filename,'rb'))

Comment: You should just give the filename directly to the PdfFileReader - or pass a file handle which you **close** yourself!

Answer (score 17):

'rb' should be on "open", not PdfFileReader.

```
merger.append(PdfFileReader(open(filename, 'rb')))
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius!